# Applications of Hodge theory to topology and analysis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, partial-differential-equations, algebraic-topology, soft-question, big-list

I am going to give a talk for the PhD students' seminar at my university. The audience is composed mainly by algebraic topologists, algebraic geometers and analysts. I have decided that I'm going to talk about Hodge theory as it has links with all of these fields, starting from the basics and going up to use it to show that deRham cohomology on compact manifolds is finite dimensional. If possible, I would like to give other interesting (and, if possible, not too hard) examples of applications. Does any of you know some?

Comment: When doing Yang-Mills theory, you get a formula for the expected dimension of the moduli space of sol'ns to the YM equation in terms of the dimensions of certain groups of harmonic forms. Then one invokes the main theorem of Hodge theory to see that this expected dimension is entirely in terms of topological information.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, I know this result in the case of Riemann surfaces (Atyiah-Bott and so on...) It could indeed be a possibility. Do you have a good reference where I could find the details?

Comment: I learned this all from Donaldson-Kronheimer, the geometry of 4-manifolds. If you email me or post another question I would be willing to write out the details (later) - I am not sure it would be a very good application for your presentation.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks, I would be very interested in hearing the details. I'll ask it as a specific question tomorrow and notify you, so that everybody can access it :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one of my favorites.

First, remember (part of) the more general version of the Hodge theorem: if $E_i$ are a sequence of vector bundles on a compact smooth manifold, and $0 \to \Gamma(E_0) \xrightarrow{d_0} \Gamma(E_1) \cdots \xrightarrow{d_n} \Gamma(E_n) \to 0$ is an elliptic complex ($d^2 = 0$ and taking symbols gives an exact sequence), then the homology groups of this complex are finite-dimensional. The standard example of an elliptic complex is $\Omega^*(M)$ with $d$.

But take $M$ to be a compact complex manifold and $E_n = \Omega^{0,n}(TM)$ with $\overline \partial$ to be the Dolbeaut complex with coefficients in $TM$. This is indeed an elliptic complex, and the theorem above implies that $\mathcal H_0$ - the space of holomorphic vector fields - is finite dimensional.

Now note that the Lie algebra of $\text{Aut}(M)$, the group of biholomorphisms of $M$, is the space of holomorphic vector fields. We've just proved that $\text{Aut}(M)$ is a finite-dimensional Lie group. This is in stark contrast to the case of $M$ noncompact; every nonvanishing holomorphic function $f$ defines a biholomorphism of $\Bbb C^2$ by $(z,w) \mapsto (z,f(z)w)$, so $\text{Aut}(\Bbb C^2)$ is very infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to present the "more general" theory (following Demailly's book). This is indeed a cool application. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: In the same set of ideas: knowing that the Dolbeaut cohomology is isomorphic to harmonic forms w/r/t a certain Laplacian means the Hodge star gives a duality. For Dolbeaut this is Serre duality. (For de Rham it should be what you get when you apply poincare duality with the universal coefficient theorem.)

Answer (score 1):

Connect Hodge theory to Algebraic geometry, I think  Lefschetz theorem on (1,1)-classes would be interesting, and a generalized one Hodge conjecture.

Kodaira imbedding theorem, Kodaira Vanishing theory may also be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) Would you be disposed to give some more details, just to have an idea of why this could be interesting to people?